# Very Simple Use of decorator pattern to generate numbers

Tags: java, decorator

I am new to design patterns and I was asked to **print numbers from 1 to 10 using decorator pattern**. I am sorry if this is trivial but I need to learn. This is what I have so far:

**Interface**

```
public interface NextNumber {
    public int getNextNumber(int n);
}
```

**Abstract Class**

```
abstract public class PrintNumbers implements NextNumber {
    protected final NextNumber next;
    protected int num;

    public PrintNumbers(NextNumber next, int num)
    {
        this.next = next;
        this.num = num;
    }

    public int getNextNumber(int num)
    {
        return num+1;
    }
}
```

**DecoratorClass**

```
public class DecoratorCount extends PrintNumbers {
    public DecoratorCount(NextNumber next, int num)
    {
        super(next, num);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int i = 0;
    }
}
```

Not sure how to proceed or even if I am going the right way. Could someone shed some light?

Comment: maybe look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern ? there is a pretty good sample of code.

Comment: How do you want to decorate your `PrintNumbers` class?

Comment: @gasan: Yes, I saw that coffee example and came up with my version of the code. The thing is, I am not sure on how its supposed to work. I know it is used to update objects dynamically but need a clearer picture.

Comment: @dash1e: Am not sure what answer to give to that.

Comment: I write you an example in the answer where I decorate the class to multiply result by 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First the decorator class does not have to extend the class that decorates but implements the same interface.

Look at this Wikipedia [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

So you can correct your decorator like this:

```
// The interface
public interface NextNumber {

     public int getNextNumber();
}

// The class to decorate
public class PrintNumbers implements NextNumber {

    protected int num;

    public PrintNumbers(int startFrom)
    {
        this.num = startFrom;
    }

    public int getNextNumber()
    {
        return num++;
    }
}

// The abstract decorator
public abstract class DecoratorCount implements NextNumber {

    private PrintNumbers pn;

    public DecoratorCount(PrintNumbers pn)
    {
       this.pn = pn;
    }
}
```

Then for example you can multiply number by 2.

```
public class DoubleDecoratorCount extends DecoratorCount {

    public DecoratorCount(PrintNumbers pn)
    {
        super(pn);
    }

    public int getNextNumber()
    {    
        return pn.getNextNumber() * 2;
    }
}
```

And you can test decorator in this way

```
public class Test {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        PrintNumbers pn = new PrintNumbers(0);
        DoubleDecoratorCount decorator = new DoubleDecoratorCount(pn);
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; ++i)
            System.out.println("value: " + decorator.getNextNumber());
    }
}
```

At this point you can write all decorators you need:

- To multiply by 3;
- To write results in letter;
- To write results in hex;
- Etc...

Comment: Thanks for this. I see you have the abstract decorator and the class to decorate separately. Now in the `DoubleDecorateeCount` do I call the `main()`?

Comment: Better you put the `main()` in a separate class. I just updated the answer with a sample.

Answer (score 3):

First, you need something that could need some decoration, then you need a decorator for that *something*. Both classes, the base class and the decorator are concrete classes and can be used directly.

Decorating a counter from 1 to 10 doesn't make much sense (numbers are always beautiful ;) ). But you could implement a basic class that prints the numbers unformatted and then implement a decorator, that adds some beauty to the printed result.

Comment: This gave me better understanding of why we use this pattern. Thanks a ton :)